# Subset data based on column with NAs but hide NA as option for subseting while keeping rows with NAs in the data

Tags: r, shiny

I have the `shiny` app below in which the table is subseted based on the min and max dates of the `selectInput()`. (I want `selectInput()` not `dateRange()`).

My data has `NAs` in dates column but I do not want to skip these rows. Also I do not want to display `NA` as choice in my `selectInput()` but on the other hand to display those rows in table.

Basically the rows with `NAs` should be always in my dataset and not be affected by my `selectInput()`.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# Creating a sample dataframe
dates <- as.Date(c("2023-01-01", "2023-02-01", NA, "2023-04-01", "2023-05-01"))
names <- c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "David", "Eve")

# Combine them into a dataframe
df <- data.frame(Date = dates, Name = names)

# Generate unique dates sorted in ascending order, including NA
unique_dates <- sort(unique(df$Date), na.last = TRUE)

# Creating a Shiny app
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Subset Data by Date Range"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("start_date", "Start Date", choices = unique_dates, selected = unique_dates[1]),
      selectInput("end_date", "End Date", choices = unique_dates, selected = unique_dates[length(unique_dates)])
    ),
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    # Subset the dataframe based on the selected date range
    subset_df <- subset(df, Date >= input$start_date & Date <= input$end_date)
    datatable(subset_df)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this is what you're trying to do currently:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tibble(
  dt = ymd(c("2023-01-01", "2023-02-01", NA, "2023-04-01", "2023-05-01")),
  nm = c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "David", "Eve")
)

choice_dates <- sort(unique(dat$dt))

#### define user interface
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Answering your question"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        "start_date",
        label = "Start Date", 
        choices = choice_dates,
        selected = min(choice_dates)
      ),
      selectInput(
        "end_date", 
        label = "End Date",
        choices = choice_dates,
        selected = max(choice_dates)
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

#### define server
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    
    outtab <- dat %>% 
      filter(
        between(dt, ymd(input$start_date), ymd(input$end_date)) | is.na(dt)
      )
    
    DT::datatable(outtab)

  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```